# How avoid password injection into textbox

Tags: .net, code-injection, password-protection

I was wondering if is possible to avoid some "bots" to inject passwords into textboxes of a Winform .NET application.

I have an application that allow users to type password directly into a textbox, or to utilize a kind of "virtual keyboard" (it hide letters before click and mix  them after this). The code is protected against "CTRL-V" within the textbox, to avoid some "bots" to push passwords within the code.

In other way, I fill a *phantom_password* everytime an authenticated entry is done (by typing or virtual keyboard) and it is that *phantom_password* that will be checked.

A sample code can be found here:

```
Public Class Form1

Dim authorized As Boolean = False
Dim PhantomPass As String = ""


   Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
       If e.Modifiers = Keys.Control Then
          e.SuppressKeyPress = True
          authorized = False
       Else
          authorized = True
       End If
   End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        If authorized = True Then
           PhantomPass += e.KeyChar
           Label1.Text = PhantomPass
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        authorized = True
        TextBox1.Text += "x"
        PhantomPass += "x"
        Label1.Text = PhantomPass
    End Sub


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None
        TextBox1.AllowDrop = False
    End Sub
    End Class
```

It´s ok, it can prevent CTRL-V within textbox and even if any other character if not directly typed or choosen by keyboard - at least, I suppose it.

My doubts:

- May I be ensured that *KeyDown* and *KeyPress* events are keyboard exclusive (executed by keyboard API)? Or can they be fired by any character that appears into textbox (like *Textchanged* event)?
- Is there some ways to change textbox values (eg. direct memory write). But in this case, if the events above won´t be fired, I will be protected.

So, is this routine a valid one against robots that inject/test passwords into a Winform app?

**NOTE**: I´m not worried about 'n' valid/invalid tries and the consequences of that action. I´m just focused in the problem to avoid, efficiently, a password injection into a Winform textbox.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Actually I don't think you ever can. If you go down to the lowest level, sending keyboard messages to a window handle is the way to "emulate" user input - and as there is no real "sender" of such a message, you can not decide whether the message came from an actual user or other software.

Comment: I hate this behaviour when used online as I use a password manager in combination with long and complex passwords. It is a PITA when I have to type it in manually and puts me off using the site. I appreciate that you're writing a desktop app and I wonder what the rationale behind not letting users use password managers/paste their passwords?

Comment: I agree whith @phuzi a lot here! Why is this a problem at all, if you're not worried about your application beeing flooded? You could always implement a delay.

Comment: Thanks by your opinion Thorsten. But if the keyboard events are *really* hardware driven, I can suppose the routine is enough to prevent bots; isn´t it?

Comment: Thanks phuzi. The problem is not related to "drag-and-drop" (we can process it normally since I don´t expect a bot could simulate these events fast enough to be a threat. Anyway, both, the application already perform a delay between tries. But I´m not focusing the procedures to manage an eventual bot success, but only if this routine is effective to avoid them. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you want to make sure that it is human user, not a bot, provide some randomly generated picture with code that user has to type or, you can ask user to give the user id in first screen, then they have to answer their own question and type password. I also seen websites asking math questions.

Comment: Thanks T.S., but like the others guys, your tip is not focusing my goal. I´m not searching for **additional procedures** to avoid "bots" - and going to utilize a Captcha into a password field is not friendly. My question must be faced strictly as I did it. Anyway, thank you very much for your tip.